# Get age > 40 from customer table where birthdate is given using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, formatting

Get the how many customers are married and single by gender whose `Age` is greater 40 using SQL Server, `birthdate` given .

Using `datediff` I am able to calculate age but need age > 40

Tried this query it display age

```
select 
    gender, maritalstatus,birthdate, 
    DATEDIFF("yyyy", birthdate, GETDATE()) as age 
from DimCustomer
```

But I need age > 40

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data, expected output and the query you tried.

Comment: Nobody has a crystal ball here!

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, but I think you want to add a `WHERE` and a `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT gender, maritalstatus, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM DimCustomer
WHERE birthdate < DATEADD(YEAR, -40, GETDATE())
GROUP BY gender, maritalstatus
```

This query would produce output like:

```
gender     maritalstatus Count
---------- ------------- -----------
Female     Married       1
Male       Married       1
Female     Single        1
Male       Single        3
```

Edit: changed the `WHERE` predicate from `WHERE DATEDIFF("yyyy", birthdate, GETDATE()) > 40` as per suggestion in comment.

Edit: added age calculation and removed counting:

```
SELECT gender, maritalstatus, birthdate, 
CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100) + DAY(GETDATE()) >= (MONTH(birthdate) * 100) + DAY(birthdate)
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,GETDATE()) ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,GETDATE())-1 END AS age
FROM DimCustomer
WHERE birthdate < DATEADD(YEAR, -41, GETDATE())
GROUP BY gender, maritalstatus, birthdate
```

This gives rows like:

```
gender     maritalstatus birthdate  age
---------- ------------- ---------- -----------
Female     Married       1942-06-30 71
Female     Married       1972-05-30 41
Male       Single        1962-12-30 50
Male       Single        1972-11-30 41
```

I can't say that this is the best or most accurate way of doing this though...

Comment: Your solution has two problems: the `WHERE` predicate isn't SARG-able and `DATEDIFF("yyyy", )` could generate misleading results (try `SELECT DATEDIFF("yyyy", '20131231', '20140101')`). You could rewrite this predicate thus: `WHERE birthdate < DATEADD(YEAR, -40, GETDATE())`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean If I'm not mistaken the fact that the query isn't SARG-able will just affect performance, and not the results? Can you elaborate on how the results can be misleading? I get the expected result (1) from your example. I do agree that your predicate is better, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: If `birthdate` = `'20131231'` and `GETDATE()` = `'20140101` then `DATEDIFF("yyyy", birthdate, GETDATE())` gives `1` year which is the expected behavior for `DATEDIFF` function but isn't the correct `age` for current person.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I see the problem now.

Comment: this does not display age > 40 I need query which would display age > 40 say

Comment: @user3054037 Until you provide an example of the desired output as asked we can only guess as to what you want. I've updated my answer with what I think you're looking for.